# Travel from UK to Schengen post brexit for a Nepalese citizen

Tags: uk, schengen, brexit

Married EU(Polish) with Settled Status and Nepalese with ILR issued in Britain want to travel for 7 days to Poland. If we travel together do we just need to show our marriage certificate and share codes?
Is Schengen visa required?

We have valid passports, ILR,settled status Polish marriage certificate.

Comment: What does "share codes" mean?

Comment: Do you have passports? What nationality? You'll also need specific ID documents to board planes, though requirements vary between airlines.

Answer (score 1):

As a citizen of Nepal, you require a visa to enter the Schengen Area:

**REGULATION (EU) 2018/1806**:

- [LIST OF THIRD COUNTRIES WHOSE NATIONALS ARE REQUIRED TO BE IN POSSESSION OF A VISA WHEN CROSSING THE EXTERNAL BORDERS OF THE MEMBER STATES](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02018R1806-20230515#tocId20)

As a Family member of an EU Citizen, such a visa will be issued free of charge and should be issued swiftly:

> [DIRECTIVE 2004/38/EC Article 5(2) - Right of entry](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A02004L0038-20110616#tocId9)
> 2. **Family members** who are not nationals of a Member State shall only be required to have an entry visa in accordance with Regulation (EC) No 539/2001 or, where appropriate, with national law. For the purposes of this Directive, possession of the valid residence card referred to in Article 10 shall exempt such family members from the visa requirement.
>
> Member States shall grant such persons every facility to obtain the necessary visas. Such visas shall be issued **free of charge as soon as possible and on the basis of an accelerated procedure**.

Comment: Poland is not normally obliged to comply with the free movement directive when the spouse of a Polish citizen applies for a visa to travel together with the Polish spouse to Poland.  It could be required to comply if the Polish spouse were exercising free movement rights, for example in Ireland.  What is the status of Poles living in the UK through the settlement scheme?  What does the withdrawal agreement have to say about this?

Comment: 3 months I am trying to reach to Polish Embassy in London with no result - my MP was invilved as well. There is no avaiable appointments in May June and July in Spanish German and French embassy in Scotland.Looks like we are going to give it a miss. .

Comment: @MariaIsMaria typically you ought to be able to get into the Schengen area by train or ferry without a visa, with only the marriage certificate (and travel documents, of course).

Comment: @MarialsMaria did you ask the consulates directly or with the third party TLS/VFS visa application centres?

Comment: @phoog As far as the fee is concerned, the Polish consulate meantions no exception for Polish citizens: [C-Type Schengen Visa - Poland in the UK - Gov.pl website](https://www.gov.pl/web/unitedkingdom/c-type-schengen-visa): **Schengen visa fee exemptions:** *Spouses of European Union citizens (when requested documents are submitted),* It does meantion an exception for [Simplified Visa procedure for family members of EU citizens](https://www.gov.pl/web/unitedkingdom/visas---general-information)

Comment: I asked directly Spanish consulate and German consulate but they directed me to third parties which in both cases said there is bo slots for appointments.

Comment: Polish consulate does mot operate via third party you need to book an appointment on their website as soon as you do so there is Error 400- reached to the technical team but nobody responded

Comment: @MariaIsMaria You can insist to submit your application directly at the consulate, and any consulate that refuses that, point them to the [Visa Code](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex%3A32009R0810#d1e1535-1-1) Art. 17-5

Comment: I dont know what is going on but there is no visa appointments at Spanish German French and Portugal embassy. Polish embassy is still unrecheable to book appointment